# Foreign Key MySQL incorrecto formato

Tags: php, mysql, sql

De este código cogido en w3school, en mysql no me lanza la segunda tabla me dice

> ## 1005 - No puedo crear tabla `pruebas`.`orders` (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Detalles…)

```
        $servername="localhost";
        $username="root";
        $password="";
        $dbname="pruebas";
        
        
        //conección 
        $conn= new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
        
        if($conn->connect_error){
            die($conn->connect_error);
        }

        
        //creación de la tabla
        $sql=" CREATE TABLE Persons (
            ID int NOT NULL,
            LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            FirstName varchar(255),
            Age int,
            PRIMARY KEY (ID)
        )";

            if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
                echo "table created";

            }else{
                echo "table failed or created";
            }
        $sql=" CREATE TABLE Orders (
            OrderID int NOT NULL,
            OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
            PersonID int,
            PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
            FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
        )";

            if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
                echo "table created";

            }else{
                echo "table failed or created";
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta línea esta mal

```
 FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
```

Pues la llave foránea `PersonID` debe apuntar a la llave primaria en la tabla `Persons` que se llama `ID`

Entonces debe quedar como

```
 FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(ID)
```

Recuerda que la sintaxis se puede leer o interpretar así

```
Llave Foránea (PersonID) Hace Referencia a la tabla Persons(en su llave primaria ID)
```

Además considera como factible colocarle un nombre a dicho `CONSTRAINT` de este modo

```
CONSTRAINT fk_Orders_Persons FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(ID)
```